# Sharing Mac OS X internet and pushing all traffic through a VMWare VM

Tags: vmware-fusion, internet, share

I have a Mac Mini connected to the internet via ethernet. I'm sharing that connection via the Mini's Airport (creating it's own wireless network). Computers can connect to the Mini via WIFI and then access the internet.

On this Mac Mini, I have a WANem VM running. I'd like to route all WIFI traffic through the WANem VM so that WANem can do its thing.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Edit: VMWare type is VMWare Fusion. I want to push all traffic through WANem so when users connect to my wireless network they have a purposefully unreliable connection. I'm setting up this environment for adding QA to our apps when networks are unreliable.

Comment: What VMware product are you using for this player?  Out of curiosity, why do you want to push all your traffic through WANem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how WANem works, but one way you could accomplish this is to set up another VM that will do the sharing, and connect the WiFi connection to it (VMware Fusion should allow you to directly connect the adapter instead of using the built-in networking). Then connect to two VMs to each other with the HostOnly network, and the WANem to the physical ethernet port.

```
WiFi
 |
directly connected to the VM
 |
VM acting as a bridge/router
 |
HostOnly Network
 |
WANem
 |
bridged network
 |
Ethernet
```

If WANem can act as the bridge, then you could simplify this like so:

```
WiFi
 |
directly connected to the VM
 |
WANem
 |
bridged network
 |
Ethernet
```

Of course you'll have to turn off your existing network sharing provided by OS X.